# Why stateful source in flink require synchronized lock

Tags: apache-flink, stateful

I am reading the flink examples here https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.8/dev/stream/state/state.html, and can not figure out the point of the existence of the synchronized block.

I have googled a lot and can not find useful answers, from flink's documentation, for each parallelism there will be a state instance, and also the **run** method in one instance of **CounterSource**  will not be called from different threads, so what is the point for the below code

```
val lock = ctx.getCheckpointLock

while (isRunning) {
  // output and state update are atomic
  lock.synchronized({
    ctx.collect(offset)

    offset += 1
  })
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Checkpointing occurs in another thread. The purpose of this lock is to prevent the source from modifying its state while a checkpoint is taking a snapshot of the state.

Comment: thank you very much, it means every time when CheckpointedFunction interface is used, race condition should be taken into consideration